# Does symmetric product functor preserve fibrations?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

I know that the symmetric product is a functor, cf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_(topology)#Functioriality.

My question is, does it preserve fibrations in the category of topological spaces? More specifically, if $p: E \to B$ is a Hurewicz fibration and $E$ and $B$ are nice enough topological spaces, then is $SP^{n}(p) : SP^{n}(E) \to SP^{n}(B)$ a Serre fibration, where $SP^{n}(X) = X^{n}/\Sigma_{n}$  and $SP^{n}(p)$ is the induced mapping, as in the notations of Wikipedia?